# How to make firefox awesomebar "switch to tab" first of the propositions list?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, awesomebar

In Firefox (actually IceWeasel but it doesn't matter) I'd like to be able to quickly switch between tabs using my keyboard. The "switch to tab" feature of the AwesomeBar is exactly what I need, but I would like to have it (if available) always as the first element of the suggested urls. Or at least to have something like having <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> perform the available "switch to tab" action instead of opening the first suggested url as enter would do.

I didn't find anything in `about:config`.

Anyone knows if it's possible and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start your query with a % sign, it will search in your currently open tabs.

There are other filters for searching in bookmarks, history, URLs...

Details here: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Location%20bar%20autocomplete#w_changing-results-on-the-fly

Comment: Precisions: one needs to type a space after `%` and then a string identifying the targeted tab which is not also a keyword for a bookmark. But still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use AwesomeBar but keybindings ctrl+page up/down and alt+1/2/3/4..9 switches between tabs.

Comment: I know this but I'd like to be able to switch based on substring of the titles or urls like the awesomebar do (and as I'm used to in Emacs to switch between buffers).